# Selenium cannot click on "Accept All" button on privacy settings popup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfTdb.png)

Hi all, I am trying to scrap the Flixbus website (link: https://global.flixbus.com/bus). Everything was going well, except when I was trying to click the Accept All button for the privacy settings, which pops out every time I open the page.

I appreciate any advice on the matter, thank you very much!

I tried the following codes to no avail:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
accept_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']")))

# Click the accept privacy settings button
accept_button.click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='//*[@id="uc-center-container"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/button[2]').click()
```

or

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
accept_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="uc-center-container"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/button[2]')))

# Click the accept privacy settings button
accept_button.click()
```

However, it just shows the no such element exception, or timeout exception. I encountered no other errors when trying to click other buttons after I manually clicked the "Accept All" button.

Answer (score 1):

The privacy settings modal is located in the shadow-root.

You can read [this](https://medium.com/@titus_on_testing/shadow-dom-in-python-selenium-df8d731b5005) article to deeper understand how to work with this.

In a nutshell, the following code should work for your website:

```
shadow_root = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#usercentrics-root'))
).shadow_root
WebDriverWait(shadow_root, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-testid="uc-accept-all-button"]'))
).click()
```